# Swift Sidebar on right

Tags: swift, sidebar

Since i need to have the sidebar open on the right, how do i change it from the left to right side? the code i use is simple:

```
    if revealViewController() != nil {
     Menubutton.target = revealViewController()
     Menubutton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))

     }
```

Also when the sidebar menu opens up it doesn't show the cells i have ( i've put both image and text on the different cells). But if i put a label in the Table view controller it shows the label when i open the sidebar menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reveal from the right side, change the selector to `rightRevealToggle`

```
Menubutton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
```

Comment: Funny thing i tried it today this morning and it didn't work. Tried now after you said and worked. thanks!. You have any idea why the table view cells doesn't show up? Do i have to make a swift file for the table view controller to make them appear or can i just type on the "cells"?

Comment: no probs. Do you fill up your table view with values and assign delegate properly? I suggest you post another question with code and explain it in more details